# Removing an uploaded file in a Webform

Tags: webform-civicrm, upload

I've set up a custom file field in CiviCRM and exposed it on a Webform. Uploading a file works fine. Coming back to the form after submitting it, the file field displays a "Change" button instead of a "Remove" button, and clicking it seems to clear out the file. However, the file does not go away.

Is there a step I'm missing on how to delete a file that was previously uploaded through `webform_civicrm` or is this a bug?

## Screenshots:

### Before

> [image: Before]

### After Upload / Before Submission

> [image: After Upload]

### After Submission / Returning to Form

> [image: After Submission]

- *On the last step, clicking "CHANGE" will appear to remove the file, but then clicking "Submit" again does not save the removal. Visiting the form again, the file is still there.*

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of the field input on your webform?

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion I just added screenshots from the process.